# xcode 8 w/jenkins xcode plugin, how to specify provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, xcode8

Error 
"Unity-iPhone requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Release" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'"

When Automatic code signing is unchecked Xcode is asking for a Release AND Debug provisioning profiles. This works when I manually build but I cannot figure out how to have Jenkins specify 2 provisioning profiles.

This is what I have set in Jenkins Custom xcodebuild arguments. 
PROVISIONING_PROFILE= CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="iPhone Distribution"

I have tried repeating the profile name. I've also tried using PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER.

In Jenkins Custom xcodebuild arguments is there a way to specify a profile for release and debug?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I don't believe you need both provisioning profiles.  Go to the Project Editor and look under Signing.  If you don't have a profile, click the dropdown and go add.  If you do... click it... you know...  Then try running it again.

Comment: Through xCode UI this is not a problem I can select bot the same provisioning profile for both Release and Debug. Its from xcodebuild command arguments were I'm not able to get a valid profile specified

Comment: That should be all you need to do though.

Comment: @ChadGeisler did you found any solution ?